# Vagrant networking host to guest

Tags: networking, vagrant

I am using Vagrant 1.9.5 with as my guest system CentOS6.5, as my host system Windows 7.

I tried this vagrant networking configurations:
`config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080` - unable to connect. 
`config.vm.network :public_network` - then I went to the Vagrant machine and see using `ifconfig` and see my public network IP and I still get a connection timeout, but I tried to `ping 172.23.34.119` - which is the number of my guest machine and it works.

I also uninstalled antivirus program, because I thought that it is affecting my firewall, but it isn't that. 
I need to get connected to my nginx.conf - which is BTW (nginx) started and running.

Comment: Is the VM's NIC in NAT or Bridged mode?  (recommend bridged any time you want to have a guest on the same network as hosts)

Comment: It has two adapters if that's what you are asking for ? First one is NAT and the second one is bridged.

Comment: The VM itself should use bridged adapters to allow the VM running to have an IP on the same network as your HOST pc.  NAT adapters, connected to/through the VM's settings, would NAT outgoing traffic.  By nature of NAT, unknown inbound traffic gets blocked. If using both bridged & nat adapter types in  your VM, you'll want to make sure the bridged adapter is your primary adapter.

Comment: I have solved the issue with a workaround, if I can call it like it. I have done a vagrant destroy and destroyed the last machine and then vagrant up again and it worked, which translates into that I have messed around and killed and started up again this bridged connection and my best guess is that I have used my bridged connection for something else. 
Anyhow thanks @TG2.